# Minecraft item tag detection not working (1.15)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I tried to give an item with a special tag to me which is executing a command while holding in the offhand. The give command works only execute doesn't.

```
minecraft:give @p minecraft:sugar{Damage:-100,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Boost\"}"},HideFlags:3,Tags:["movement_charge_item"],Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:power",lvl:0}]} 1

minecraft:execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,tag:movement_charge_item}]}] run say hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom list named `Tags` is different from `tag`. Instead, put `Tags:["movement_charge_item"]` inside `tag:{}`.

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,tag:{Tags:["movement_charge_item"]}}]}] run say hello
```